Why doesn't Airbus use NLF nacelle for their aircraft?
Why doesn't Airbus use NLF (Natural Laminar Flow) nacelle for their aircraft?  320neo,330neo,350

Do you have a source for this claim?

The nacelle is generally not designed nor manufactured by the aircraft designer/manufacturer. For CFMI engines, nacelles have been designed and manufactured by Aircelle (now Safran).

The NLF nacelle is identified by the extended metal surface lip region. This feature appeared on the 737max, 787, and 777x, but I never found the same feature on the Airbus new plane.

Although the supplier is generally responsible for the nacelle manufacture, whether to choose the NLF nacelle tec is up to the aircraft companies.

It seems NAIAD testbed for CFMI engines wasn't successful.
